# Disprove $P(B)<1\Rightarrow P(A \vert B^C)=1-P(A\vert B)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

My idea to disprove is to assume that events $A,B$ are independent (then $A,B^C$ are independent too) and we would have: $$P(A\vert B^C)=P(A)\neq 1-P(A)=P(A\vert B)$$

However I wonder if there is an alternative proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea is great and obviously works for the reason you cited. I'm not sure what you mean by "an alternative proof" in this context; to disprove something like this, your job is only to prove a counterexample, and you've done that. I suppose it might be mildly more satisfying if you put an actual example to it, such as something involving dice or cards or coins, but that's trivial to do if you just select any two independent processes.

Maybe what you mean by an "alternative proof" is that this can be done with *dependent* events; if that's what you mean, then the answer is still yes. Consider rolling a die; let $A$ denote the event that the die is $1, 2,$ or $3$, and let $B$ denote the event that the die is $1$ or $2$. Then $P(A \mid B) = 1$ and $P(A \mid B^c) = 1/4$.

This statement is one of those false equations where you don't have to look hard for a counterexample. The times where it *is* true are remarkable accidents.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A$ be the event of a die showing a 6. Let $B$ be the event of a coin landing on Head. The two events are independent, so $P(A)=1/6=P(A|B)=P(A|B^c)$, so $P(A|B^c)=1/6\ne 1-P(A)$.

The reasoning is faulty because $P(A|B)\ne 1-P(A)$ in general, even for independent events.

Comment: I think this is a precise recreation of the argument given by the OP....

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be finding a better clarification for both sides of the equation.

Since A and B are independent, we have

```
P(A|B^C) = P(A) * P((B^C)^C) = P(A) * P(B),
1 - P(A|B) = 1 - P(A) * P(B^C) = 1 - P(A) * (1 - P(B)) = P(A) * P(B) + (1 - P(A)).
```

Since `1 - P(A) = 0` doesn’t always hold, we cannot prove the equation. (I’m guessing the condition should be `P(A) < 1` so that we can prove the equation is strictly wrong?)